# Insert into a binary tree using dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree

We have a simple binary trees
We need to Insertion into a tree using a function INSERT(Tree,Key,left,right)

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(A,key=None,left=None,right=None):
        A.key=key
        A.l=left
        A.r=right
```

The tree most be like this

```
A = { 
     'r' : ['a','b'], 
     'a' : ['c','d'], 
     'b' : ['e','f'],
     'c' : ['','h'], 
     'd' : ['i', 'j'], 
     'e' : ['k',''], 
     'f' : ['',''],
     'h' : ['',''], 
     'i': ['',''], 
     ....
}
```

We need to insert to the tree using our function INSERT(Tree,Key,left,right)
we did a try :

```
   def noeud(key, left = None, right = None) :
            return {'key': key, 'left' : fg, 'right': fd}
    

    A= Tree()
    
    def Insert(Tree,Key,left,right):
        dic = noeud(Key,left,right)
        # check if the key already exist in the tree (dic keys mosy be unique)
        if Key in Tree: return print('key already exist ')
        else:
            # here im lost
```

Comment: You are showing the tree to be both a plain dict *and* a (possibly nested) custom type. Which is it? Which one are you struggling with?

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: Hi, please we have problem adding a new item to the tree we create a function (INSERT with 4 parameters the original Tree + the key + left value + right value ) , s the question is : how we can add the value to the tree ?   def Insert(Tree,Key,left,right):
    dic = noeud(Key,left,right)
    # check if the key already exist in the tree (dic keys mosy be unique)
    if Key in Tree: return print('key already exist ')
    else:
        # here im lost 
        dic.key=Key
        dic.left=left
        dic.right=right

Comment: There are actually quite a few flaws in your code. Was this predefined or did you come up with it yourself?

Comment: it's predefined structures for the A={...}

Comment: So the `class` part is not predefined? Because that is confusing... as it introduces a different data structure... Please clearly define what is input, what is expected output (really provide the expected output in full), and what is your code and what is predefined code.

Comment: Yes the class is not predefined i did my self :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need to define a class or to define a factory function like `noeud`. Neither of these can be used in the dictionary presentation of the tree.

So keep it simple. When you get a key, add that key to the dictionary, with as value a list with two keys (left and right).

The only "advanced" thing you could add is a verification whether left and right already exist in the tree, and if not, add them as leaves (so their value is ['', '']). I would not reject a call to `insert` when the key is already present in the tree. In that case, let that new call override the previous one. This will be useful to override those automatically created leaves.

Code:

```
def insert(tree, key, left, right):
    tree[key] = [left, right]
    A.setdefault(left, ['', ''])
    A.setdefault(right, ['', ''])

# demo

A = {}
insert(A, 'r', 'a', 'b')
insert(A, 'a', 'c', 'd')
insert(A, 'b', 'e', 'f')
print(A)
```